# appendTo function run twicely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an append child function and I have stored the new child as a variable which is named 'newNode'. But when I console newNode it returns twice. why? I am invoking this function on a click event.

```
function appendNewStage() {
 var parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas__row');
 var newStage = `<ul class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-
                 list stage">
                 <li>
                 <span class="ci-journey-interactions-box__droppable-
                 element ci-droppable"></span>
                 </li>
                 </ul>`;

 var position = $(parent).find("ul:last").position();
 var width = $(parent).find("ul:last").outerWidth();
 newNode = $(newStage).appendTo(parent);
 console.log(newNode);
 if (remain.length > 0) {
     newNode.html(remain);
 }
 $(newNode).find('li:first-child').addClass('first-child');
 newNode.css({
     "position": "absolute",
     "left": (width + position.left - 89),
     "top": (position.top + 140)
 });
 var dropArea = $(newNode).find('.ci-droppable');
 dropArea.droppable();
 dropArea.droppable({
     accept: ".ci-draggable",
 });
 elementSelect(newNode);
 };
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: It could simply bejQuery logging elements it handles. Have you tried to output into a test div or something?

Comment: Does `$('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas__row').length == 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I console newNode it returns twice. why?

If you're seeing two entries in the jQuery object `newNode` refers to, it's because there are two `.ci-journey-interactions-canvas__row` elements. `appendTo` duplicates the structure you pass it when there are multiple target parents, and returns a new jQuery object containing all of those structures. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

> If there is more than one target element, however, **cloned copies of the inserted element will be created** for each target except the last, **and that new set (the original element plus clones) is returned**.

*(my emphasis)*

Here's a simpler example:

```js
var newNode = $("<span>x</span>").appendTo(".foo");
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- Only one span
console.log(newNode.length);            // 2
console.log(newNode[0].nodeName);       // span
console.log(newNode[1].nodeName);       // span
console.log(newNode[0] === newNode[1]); // false
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```